# What is $\;\int xe^{-x^2} \,dx\;?$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

What is $$\int xe^{-x^2} dx\quad?$$

I used substitution to rewrite it as $$\int -\dfrac{1}{2}e^u\, du$$ but this is too hard for me to evaluate. When I used wolfram alpha for $\int e^{-x^2} dx$ I got a weird answer involving a so called error function and pi and such (I'm guessing it has something to do with Euler's identity, but I'm fairly certain this is above my textbook's level).

Comment: $-\frac12\int e^udu$ is too hard to evaluate?

Comment: $e^{-x^2} dx$ is the Gaussian integral, but that's not what you want to evaluate! $\int -\dfrac{1}{2}e^u\, du$ is easy though, the integral of $e^u$ is just $e^u$

Comment: I think you entered $e^{-x^2}dx$ in Wolfram and you got the antiderivatives of $e^{-x^2}$ which are indeed not "elementary" and invlolve the so-called error function. But $\int xe^{-x^2}dx=-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2}+C$ is "elementary". Note that $xe^{-x^2}dx$ is called a differential $1$-form. You probably wanted an integral sign in front.

Comment: For fun, try integrating $x^n e^{-x^2}$ in terms of the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ if necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your substitution was spot on. You put $$u = -x^2 \implies du = -2x\;dx \implies x\,dx = -\frac 12\, du$$

And having substituted, you obtained $$\int -\dfrac{1}{2}e^u\, du$$
Great work. But I think you gave up too early!: $$-\frac 12\int e^u \, du = -\frac 12 e^u + C,\tag{1}$$ and recall, $u = f(x), \;du = f'(x)\,dx$, so $(1)$ is equivalent to $$-\frac 12 \int e^{f(x)}\,f'(x)\,dx = -\frac 12 e^{f(x)} + C$$

---

So we can integrate as follows, and then back-substitute: 
 $$\int -\dfrac{1}{2}e^u\, du = -\frac 12 \int e^u \,du = -\frac 12 e^u + C = -\frac 12 e^{-x^2} + C\tag{2}$$

Now, to remove all doubts, simply differentiate the result given by $(2)$: $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\frac 12 e^{-x^2} + C\right) = -\frac 12(-2x)e^{-x^2} = xe^{-x^2}$$
which is what you set out to integrate: $\color{blue}{\bf x}e^{-x^2} \neq e^{-x^2}$

Comment: I'm totally confused. If you for example take the derivative of $e^{-x^2}$ you get $-2e^{-x^2}x$. So why would it in this case be exactly the same?

Comment: Right, but if you differentiate $-\frac 12 e^{-x^2} + C$, you get $-\frac 12(-2x)e^{-x^2} = xe^{-x^2}$

Comment: Still don't understand this at all. Yeah, you get the correct result, but why is 0.5 times the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ equal to itself?

Comment: $-\dfrac{1}{2} \int e^u du = - \dfrac{1}{2} e^u + C$, but when you differentiate it you get a different answer

Comment: You're missing the factor of $x$ in the expression $xe^{-x^2}$. Back substitute, and use the chain rule...see my edited post.

Comment: I'm still totally not getting this, why you can say that $e^u = e^u$ in this case, since $u=-x^2$ and you'd think that you have to multiply the $e^u$ by something

Comment: That's what $u-substitution$ allows us to do: recall, we took into account what $u$ is equal to when we substituted. So it is legitimate to treat $u$ as the variable of integration, since we are integrating with respect to $u$: that's what $du$ tells us. Then **after** integrating with respect to $u$, we back-substitute to obtain the integrand in terms of $x$.

Comment: You're right. Thank you for all your help. I guess I was just mindlessly doing exercises without knowing with du/dx etc. mean.

Comment: You're welcome, Stephen.

Answer (score 4):

Let $u = -x^2$. It follows that $du = -2xdx$. So then

$$\int xe^{-x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int -2xe^{-x^2}dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int e^udu = -\frac{1}{2}e^u + C = -\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2} + C.$$

Answer (score 3):

The problem is to find
$$\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx.$$
So we are trying to find the functions $F(x)$ such that
$$F'(x)=xe^{-x^2}.$$
We can easily verify, by differentiating, that $F(x)=-\frac{1}{2}{e^{-x^2}}$ "works," and therefore the general $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=xe^{-x^2}$ is given by $F(x)=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}+C$.

The problem of finding a function $G(x)$ such that $G'(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is entirely different, even though the two functions $xe^{-x^2}$ and $e^{-x^2}$ are closely related. It turns out that there is no *elementary* function whose derivative is $e^{-x^2}$. Roughly speaking, an *elementary function* is a function built up from the familiar functions by using addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and *composition* (substitution).

So $xe^{-x^2}$ and $e^{-x^2}$ are elementary functions. The first has an elementary indefinite integral. The second doesn't. The second function is very important for many applications. There **is** a function whose derivative is $e^{-x^2}$, and that function is useful. It just happens not to be an elementary function.

Because the function $e^{-x^2}$ is so important, an antiderivative of a closely related function has been given a name, the *error function*, often written as $\operatorname{erf}(x)$. That is what Alpha was talking about. If you ever study probability or statistics, you will become deeply familiar with the error function.

**Back** to our problem! We are trying to integrate $xe^{-x^2}$. We already did that earlier, by a "guess and check" method. But that is not entirely satisfactory, so we now use a standard method, substitution.

As in your post, let $u=-x^2$. Then $du=-2x\,dx$, so $x\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\,du$. Substitute. We get
$$\int xe^{-x^2}\,dx=\int -\frac{1}{2} e^u\,du=-\frac{1}{2}e^u+C=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}+C.$$
Finding $\int e^u\,du$ was easy. We know that the derivative of $e^t$ with respect to $t$ is $e^t$, so $\int e^t\,dt=e^t+C$.

Try the following closely related problems.

$1.$ Find $\int  e^{5x+17}\,dx$.

$2.$ Find $\int (\cos x)e^{\sin x}\,dx$.